# Google Analytics not recording any hits on country subdomain. Google tag assistant reports net::ERR_ABORTED

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, country-specific

We are having a bit of trouble in setting up country-specific subdomains in Google Analytics and it is not registering traffic on one of the subdomains.

So the domains are example.com & nz.example.com. when someone from NZ visits example.com, they are automatically redirected to nz.example.com.

Both the domains have separate GTM code setup and separate analytics property but the sub-domain is not registering any hits. I tried sending test traffic as well. A detailed look into tag manager gave me this error

[image]

The codes are correctly setup in head & body. I tried reading a lot of guides but not really helpful.

Should I continue with the current setup of different tracking id for each subdomain or should I go with single analytics code on example.com, use cookie function in tag manager and set up different filters in analytics.

Comment: Try to publish your container.